# Question regarding the google app script access permission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi All I have a question

We hired a Google Apps Script developer who was able to complete the script, which we named "Cashflow Script." We are now attempting to execute it, however it requires a large number of full access permissions, such as "write" and "read" on the database (see, edit, create and delete all your google slides presentation)

I have included the picture shown below for reference purposes. Now my question is if we should execute it. Would the developer we hire have complete access of the permission we granted?

[image]

Comment: About `Would the developer we hire have complete access of the permission we granted?`, when I saw your showing image, this script can access all Slides, Documents, Spreadsheets, and Forms. If you want to make the user access to only the specific file (Document, Slides, Spreadsheet, and so on), how about using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`? In this scope, the user can access only the files created by that Google Apps Script project. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, we are a financing company so what on our google drive, we don't want to see it by others, my question is if we allow this will the developer that we hire will see our files in google drive? particular to this spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in your situation, how about the following 2 patterns? 1. If you want to make users access to your Google Drive, it uses the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` as I have already mentioned. I think that this might be a simple way. But, in this case, it is required to limit the scope by the administrator. Because the scopes can be changed with the script editor.

Comment: 2. If you don't want to make users access to your Google Drive, it uses the service account. When the service account is used, the user can access only the files in the service account. I think that this might be a bit complicated. Because, in this case, it is required to use Google APIs using the access token instead of each prepared method of Google Apps Script. In this case, I think that it is required to also limit the scopes. Because, when Google Apps Script project is your Google Drive, by changing the scopes, the user can access to your file.

Comment: As 3rd pattern, although I'm not sure about your actual development environment,  when the Google Apps Script project is put in the user's Google Drive, how about sharing the sample files by the shared drive and sharing the files? By this, the user can access only the shared files.

Comment: For example, when you are using Google workspace and you have the permission for managing Google workspace and you want to add the user to your Google workspace, I think that you can manage the limitation of the Google Apps Script project. If you are not using Google workspace, how about developing the Google Apps Script on the user's Google Drive? But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if these were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Do you own this script? Do you have access to it? The script will get access to your account, not the developer per se. And you can always revoke the permission.